# how to catch "free(): invalid pointer:"

Tags: c++, pointers, try-catch

how to catch/check/test for an invalid pointer?

m_gTest declared in .h file
not initialized

```
try
{
    delete m_gTest;
}
catch(...)
{
    std::cout << "catch" << '\n';
}
```

instead of catching it

```
free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000006053b8 ***
```

how to catch/check/test for an invalid pointer?

```
temp[i] = m_gTest[i];
```

does not cause error, but if m_gTest is invalid, then anything put in temp will be wrong

o, and have used

```
if(m_gTest != NULL)
```

Comment: The fact that you need to catch free/delete on an invalid pointer means you're doing whatever you're doing wrong!

Comment: I would recommend setting all pointers to `nullptr` by default, and checking for that instead of validity. Just keep track of your pointers!

Comment: @Amav That just gives you a false sense of security, and is generally a waste of time.

Comment: @NeilButterworth A false sense of security? So you are saying to NOT initialize your pointers? That seems likely to produce bugs

Comment: @Amav "So you are saying to NOT initialize your pointers?" Please point out where I said any such things.

Comment: According to the OP: "m_gTest declared in .h file not initialized" By suggesting not to set a pointer to `nullptr` since it creates a false sense of security, you are implying to not initialize it or set it to a default value of some sort.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah You don't need to check pointers for null. `delete 0;` is legal. The problem is in pointers with other values, and there is no way to detect good values from bad. The solution lies in eliminating the bug, not runtime checks.

Comment: _PLEASE_ just use the modern language features such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` if you can.  I'm very suspicious of this variable you've declared in your header, too.  Chances are you forgot to declare it as `extern`, and it might be uninitialized because there are multiple copies of it.  There are other problems with an external global variable too, such as the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)

Comment: @paddy, it is not to be a global. it is not initialized, because i forgot to initialize it. just want to know how to catch any bugs i forgot, and to tell which is the bug.

Comment: You'll probably find that "_free(): invalid pointer_" is not actually an exception but another error reporting mechanism that cannot be caught, like a debug assertion. It is probably generated by non-c++ code, for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally impossible to check if a pointer is "valid", given only the pointer. Certainly, calling delete on an "invalid" pointer will not throw an exception, except perhaps via undefined behaviour.

Basically, your code needs to explicitly track whether a pointer is "valid" or not. Or better use smart pointers, such as std::unique_ptr.

Comment: I temporarily downvoted, but then decided to [post this question instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44424979/1270789).

Comment: @Ken I don't see why you would have downvoted it, and "Certainly, calling delete on an "invalid" pointer will not throw an exception, except perhaps via undefined behaviour. " is an answer to your question.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer, but I just wanted to get a clear statement on that as I realised I wasn't clear in my own mind on that point.

Comment: there seems to be no way to catch "undefined behaviour". please explain "except perhaps via undefined behaviour. "

Comment: @michaeleric What's to explain? The undefined behaviour can include throwing an exception. Or exploding your computer.

Comment: catch(...) is suppose to catch everything that is thrown. how to catch/detect undefined behaviour before program crashes?

Comment: @michaeleric yes, but that requires something to have been thrown. `free` is a good ol' C function and C knows not what an exception is and thus cannot throw an exception. You also cannot catch signals such as segfaults and floating point exceptions (because it turns out FPE isn't an exception in the C++ sense), asserts, aborts, and many other forms of program-crashing ninjitsu. Most of the time you don't want to intercept, handle them, and continue because they mean your program is utterly hosed and should be allowed to die peacefully.

Comment: @michaeleric The point is that there is no guarantee that undefined behaviour will throw an exception in the first place, so you can write whatever code you like to cope with undefined behaviour but there is nothing defined that says your code will ever be invoked. The solution is not to write more code, it is to fix the code that engages in undefined behaviour in the first place.