# Can undefined behaviour cause an exception in a function defined as never throwing an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, undefined-behavior

I was looking at [a description of `delete[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/) and it says:

> **Exception safety**
>   **No-throw guarantee**: this function never throws exceptions.

But it adds:

> Notice that an invalid value of *ptr* causes undefined behavior.

I suspect that UB can include throwing an exception and the guarantee is only good for valid pointers, but I just thought I'd check.

Comment: You want us to define the behaviour that is not defined?!

Comment: Yes, all bets are off with undefined behavior.

Comment: Undefined behavior can do anything.

Comment: It could throw an exception but disable the exception catching mechanism. When undefined behavior has occurred, you can't make any assumptions, since it could have corrupted any part of the runtime data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Undefined behavior" means that the language definition does not tell you what the code does. So, yes, anything can happen, including blowing past a `noexcept` specifier. After all, there are no rules... (well, your compiler may provide rules, but relying on that is not portable).